# trinidad project with glassfish server does not work

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, trinidad

Can Anyone Help Me to Configure my project on **Trinidad 1.2.11** framework on **glassfish 4.1** Server I tried many times but it didn't work! still have this

```
Error :
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
And GlassFish get this warning 
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.el.lang.EvaluationContext.notifyBeforeEvaluation(EvaluationContext.java:131)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperty(UIXComponentELTag.java:125)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.UIXEditableValueTag.setProperties(UIXEditableValueTag.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.core.input.CoreInputTextTag.setProperties(CoreInputTextTag.java:255)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperties(UIXComponentELTag.java:112)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentELTag.createComponent(UIComponentELTag.java:230)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.createChild(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:504)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:742)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.doStartTag(UIXComponentELTag.java:67)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_tr_inputText_0(Login_jsp.java:210)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_tr_form_0(Login_jsp.java:163)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_f_view_0(Login_jsp.java:120)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:74)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:630)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$OverrideDispatch.dispatch(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Warning:   Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.el.lang.EvaluationContext.notifyBeforeEvaluation(EvaluationContext.java:131)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperty(UIXComponentELTag.java:125)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.UIXEditableValueTag.setProperties(UIXEditableValueTag.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.core.input.CoreInputTextTag.setProperties(CoreInputTextTag.java:255)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperties(UIXComponentELTag.java:112)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentELTag.createComponent(UIComponentELTag.java:230)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.createChild(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:504)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:742)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.doStartTag(UIXComponentELTag.java:67)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_tr_inputText_0(Login_jsp.java:210)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_tr_form_0(Login_jsp.java:163)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_f_view_0(Login_jsp.java:120)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:74)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:630)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$OverrideDispatch.dispatch(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.el.lang.EvaluationContext.notifyBeforeEvaluation(EvaluationContext.java:131)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperty(UIXComponentELTag.java:125)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.UIXEditableValueTag.setProperties(UIXEditableValueTag.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.taglib.core.input.CoreInputTextTag.setProperties(CoreInputTextTag.java:255)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.setProperties(UIXComponentELTag.java:112)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentELTag.createComponent(UIComponentELTag.java:230)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.createChild(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:504)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.findComponent(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:742)
    at javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase.doStartTag(UIComponentClassicTagBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.UIXComponentELTag.doStartTag(UIXComponentELTag.java:67)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_tr_inputText_0(Login_jsp.java:210)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_tr_form_0(Login_jsp.java:163)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_f_view_0(Login_jsp.java:120)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:74)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet._serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:630)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.context.ExternalContextDecorator.dispatch(ExternalContextDecorator.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.context.FacesContextFactoryImpl$OverrideDispatch.dispatch(FacesContextFactoryImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.executePageToBuildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:153)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:155)
    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: We have a 1.2 project running on GlassFish 4.1. Did you try to find out which input text is giving you problems with the expression?

Comment: at the login form but its not the problem someone told me to change some jar files in the server but i dontno what should i change exactly

Comment: We didn't had to change any JAR files

Answer (score 1):

`ValueExpression.getValue(null)` throws this in EL spec version 3.0. This would work fine in EL spect version 2.2. Just pass a valid `ELContext` object to prevent this error.